# Return text before one of two patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have the following two strings:

```
$str='http://website.com/abc/?var=abc';
$str='http://website.com/abc/?xvar=123&var=xyz';
```

I would like to change $str to everything before either "?var=" or "&var=" using PHP.

For instance, given the two examples, $str will be converted to:

```
$str='http://website.com/abc/';
$str='http://website.com/abc/?abc=123';
```

Thank you

Way below solutions were tested:

```
<?php
    $str='http://website.com';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');
    $str='http://website.com/';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');
    $str='http://website.com/abc';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');
    $str='http://website.com/abc/';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');
    $str='http://website.com/abc/?var=abc';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');
    $str='http://website.com/abc/?xvar=123&var=xyz';
    echo('string-'.$str.'<br>');
    echo('opt1-'.opt1($str).'<br>');
    echo('opt2-'.opt2($str).'<br>');

function opt1($str) {
    return preg_replace('/[?&]var=.*$/', '', $str);
}
function opt2($str) {
    preg_match('/(.*)[\?\&]var=/',$str2,$m);
    return $m[1];
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried preg_replace functions as yet for your replacing?

Comment: I was messing around with preg_match().  Should I change to preg_replace()?

Comment: yes, use preg_replace first instead, then you should be on the right track to get your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[?&]var=.*$/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you mean `$str='http://website.com/abc/?xvar=123';` in your second example, this should work:

```
preg_match('/(.*)[\?\&]var=/',$str2,$m);
echo $m[1];
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't implement it correctly (see my original post for how I tested it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and retrieve the string before the `?var`,

```
$str = strstr($str, "?var=", true);
echo str; //outputs - http://website.com/abc/
//Similarly for the other needle
$str = strstr($str, "&var=", true);
echo $str; //outputs - http://website.com/abc/?abc=123
```